# How are the components related

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider an ordinary three dimensional vector $\vec{A}$. Now let the vector $\vec{A'}$ be the vector that is obtained by rotating $\vec{A}$ counterclockwise by an angle $\phi$ about the $z$ axis. Let $\theta$ be the angle between the projection of $\vec{A}$ in the $x-y$ plane and the $x$ axis.

How was the following obtained?

$$\vec{A_x}'=\sqrt{\vec{A_x}^2+\vec{A_y}^2}\cos(\phi+\theta)$$ $$=\sqrt{\vec{A_x}^2+\vec{A_y}^2}(\cos\phi\cos\theta-\sin\phi\sin\theta)=\vec{A_x}\cos\phi - \vec{A_y}\sin\phi.$$

And similary $$\vec{A_y}'= \vec{A_x}\sin\phi+\vec{A_y}\cos\phi.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $z$ value doesn't change, so we only need to consider $B = \begin{bmatrix} A_x \\ A_y\end{bmatrix}$.

Let $M = |B|$.  It is a rotation, so $M = |B'|$.  The angle of $B$ is $\theta$ and the angle of $B'$ is $\theta + \phi$.

So

$$\begin{align}
B' &= M ~\angle~ (\theta + \phi) \\
   &= \begin{bmatrix} M \cos(\theta + \phi) \\ M \sin(\theta + \phi) \end{bmatrix} \\
   &= \begin{bmatrix} M \cos(\theta)\cos(\phi) - M\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi) \\
                      M \cos(\theta)\sin(\phi) + M \sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) \end{bmatrix} \\
   &= \begin{bmatrix} A_x\cos(\phi) - A_y\sin(\phi) \\
                      A_x\sin(\phi) + A_y\cos(\phi) \end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align}$$

$$A' = \begin{bmatrix} A_x\cos(\phi) - A_y\sin(\phi) \\
                       A_x\sin(\phi) + A_y\cos(\phi)  \\
                       A_z \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: What is the notation $\angle$? Also, why is it defined as $B'=M\angle(\theta+\phi)$?

Comment: $\angle$ is polar notation.  $A ~\angle~ B$ is a vector of length $A$ and angle $B$.  The magnitude is $M$ because rotations don't change the angle, and the angle is $\theta + \phi$ because the angle starts at $\theta$ and increases by $\phi$.